# Moving register content to memory address in another register in x86_64

Tags: c, assembly, clang

Doing some inline assembly in clang (basically guessing my way through by using various references) and I'm trying to move the contents of `%rdi` to the address pointed to by `%rdx`. However none of my syntax works, this:

```
mov %rdi, ptr %rdx
```

gives:

```
error: expected relocatable expression
```

What's wrong? What is the syntax in inline assembly in clang to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter thought your question lacks research effort. Other than that, I can't see a legitimate reason for a downvote. (But you should remove that edit from your question, it doesn't belong there.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what clang's assembly syntax might be exactly, but the AT&T syntax used by gcc/gas would be:

```
movq %rdi, (%rdx)
```

The Intel/Microsoft assembly syntax would be:

```
mov qword ptr [rdx], rdi
```

Comment: Thanks. I searched at least 50 times on google and somehow none of my searches brought up this particular syntax (parenthesis). I've also worked a bit with assembler but not so much with the gcc style one and never seen this.

Comment: @Hannes: everything I know about the (awful) AT&T gas syntax, I learned from looking at the output of `gcc -S some-c-file.c`.